# Convert .jpg,.png,.xls,.doc,.gif,.rtf,.csv,.txt file type to PDF using Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, pdf, pdf-conversion

Is there any converter using which I can convert .jpg,.png,.xls,.doc,.gif,.rtf,.csv,.txt file type to PDF using Codeigniter?

Comment: What do you mean 'any file type'? How do you want convert to pdf MP3 for example?

Comment: https://pdfcrowd.com/blog/2011/04/18/convert-html-to-pdf-in-php.html may be its helpful @Dipanwita Das

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

try [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) it's a document converter. you can call it via exec.
to convert the images you have to create a document first. e.g. a html file
there are a lot of examples on the demo site. To convert to pdf you need LaTeX installed.

older versions of libreoffice (up to 4.2.4.2) can convert doc, xls,... to
pdf - (maybe the current version has fixed the function to create pdf).

additionally you could create your own pdf with [PDF](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php)